# How do I incrementally update my Git branch with stored procedures after a database refresh?

Tags: git, stored-procedures

Stored procedures are tied to the database.  We regularly refresh the database to obtain a fresh set of data.  Alongside the refresh, our codebase is restored to the Production version.  Not all source may be promoted back into the environment immediately, such as for testing or bug fixes.  However, I want my Git branch to reflect the source currently installed on the database.

So far, I've been destructively deleting and recreating my branch

```
git checkout <branchname>
git checkout -b <branchname_backup> #Back up in order to save history
git branch -d <branchname>
git push <remote> :<branchname>
git checkout master
git checkout -b <branchname>
// Merges into <branchname>
git push <remote> <branchname>
```

Is there an incremental way, without deleting history, to do this after every database refresh?

Comment: You haven’t been deleting history. Just the reference to it. You’d need to run the gc before any commits get deleted. Could you not reset the branch to a new commit instead?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Well, that's the underlying behavior, not featured functionality.  I'm also technically backing the branch up (temporarily) so not "losing", but I'd rather have it all one a single timeline, especially if I need to reference previous actions before a refresh.